# Is this the intended behavior of textbox and label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I set the value of the controls when the DOM loads. I have this super simple code on aspx page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=textBox2.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=textBox1.ClientID %>').val());
            $('#<%=lblVal.ClientID %>').html($('#<%=textBox1.ClientID %>').val());

        });
    </script>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox1" Text="Test data" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox2" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblVal" Text="Old Data" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />
```

In my button click event handler I have this code:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Write(textBox2.Text);
        Debug.Write(lblVal.Text);
    }
```

The thing that came shocking to me lblVal has it's old value. Setting value in javascript doesn't really have any effect on label whereas the textbox2's data is reflected on the server. Is the intended behavior of textbox and label? This came as a bit of surprise to me because I never came across this thing previously.

Comment: No they should retain their value; I change the values of textboxes and hidden fields with JS and it posts back to the server OK....

Comment: @Brian: I am not talking about hidden field. You can change the value of label and try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label will get rendered to an HTML `label` tag, not a form field. Therefore it does not have a value that is posted when the form is submitted, and the value you get restored in the postback is from ViewState. Form fields (e.g. a ASP TextBox which becomes an `input`) will post their value and this will override the value in viewstate.

You could get around this by instead having a hidden input which you update with javascript, and then in your postback update the label with the contents of that instead.

Comment: Actually in my company I am working on one payment system where the total amount to be charged is stored in label. So I just was checking whether I could hack it and went ahead and changed the value through Firebug but to my suprise the old value was only charged :p. I was unable to hack the system.

Answer (score 0):

An asp:Label control renders to a span, and is therefore not a form element, and its changed contents will not be posted to the server.